# Boolean value outside the function doesn't get changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I'm learning Python and can't get my `bool` to change from "True" to "False" in my `replay` function. I've scoured StackOverflow, but can't find an answer.

I've tried `canPlay = False` and `canPlay = not canPlay`. But that's not working.

Any suggestions?

```
import random
from random import randint

# welcome message
print("Welcome to the number guessing game!")

# get the random seed
seedValue = input("Enter random seed: ")
random.seed(seedValue)
canPlay = True

def play():

    randomNumber = randint(1, 100)
    numberOfGuesses = 1
    guessValue = ""

    while guessValue != randomNumber:

        # prompt the user for a guess
        guessValue = int(input("\nPlease enter a guess: "))

        # provide higher/lower hint
        if guessValue == randomNumber:
            print(f"Congratulations. You guessed it!\nIt took you {numberOfGuesses} guesses.")
        elif guessValue > randomNumber:
            print("Lower")
        else:
            print("Higher")

        # increment the count
        numberOfGuesses += 1

def replay():
    
    playAgain = input("\nWould you like to play again (yes/no)? ")

    if playAgain == "no":
        canPlay = False # not changing values
        canPlay = not canPlay # this doesn't work either
        print("Thank you. Goodbye.")

while canPlay == True:
    play()
    replay()
```

Comment: You need to learn about Python scoping rules, especially about mutating global variables

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, OK. So . . . Would you care to enlighten me or are you just going to leave me hanging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a `global` keyword inside the `reply()` function, you can change the value of the `canPlay` variable in the global namespace which is then needed in the condition of while statement `while canPlay == True:`:

```
def replay():
    global canPlay  # <------------------ Here

    playAgain = input("\nWould you like to play again (yes/no)? ")

    if playAgain == "no":
        canPlay = False # not changing values
        canPlay = not canPlay # this doesn't work either
        print("Thank you. Goodbye.")
```

If you do not insert that line, `canPlay` would be a local variable for `reply()` function, so it can't change global variables or be accessed by other statements outside the `reply` function.